# Laravel Eloquent Query with AND inside orWhere()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
$query->orWhere(['member_id'=> $participant['id'], "event_id"=>$event_id, 'member_status'=>'1'])
```

on Debugging the Above query using toSql() , i Found this

```
select * from group_members where group_members.`event_id` = 5 and group_members.`event_id` is not null and (member_id = ? and event_id = ? and member_status = ?) or (member_id = ? or event_id = ? or member_status = ?)
```

However I want it to be like,

```
select * from group_members where group_members.`event_id` = 5 and group_members.`event_id` is not null and (member_id = ? and event_id = ? and member_status = ?) or (member_id = ? and event_id = ? and member_status = ?)
```

How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query->where(function($query) {
    $query->where(['member_id'=> $participant['id'], "event_id"=>$event_id, 'member_status'=>'1']);
})->orWhere(function($query) {
    $query->where(['member_id'=> $participant['id'], "event_id"=>$event_id, 'member_status'=>'1']);
});
```